# Is there a way to read from a file without storing the information somewhere?

Tags: c

Is there a way to read from a file without storing the information somewhere?

If I use `fscanf(in, "%s %d", string, &number)` I'm forced to store `%s` in `string` and `%d` in `number`. Is there a way not to do that? I need to scan because I want to know how many records there are in that file.

By "records" I mean the occurrences of `%s` and `%d`.

Comment: You can go through the file byte by byte and count the delimiters

Comment: First you need to define what a "record" *is*. Is it a line? A space-delimited "word"? Something else?

Comment: fgetc(in) might help.

Answer (score 8):

<sup>*The original version of the question listed only `"%s"` in the format; it was updated to ask about `"%s %d"` as the record format.*</sup>

An odd requirement in many ways.  You can use assignment suppression, but be cautious as it limits your error checking.  Note that the `%s` conversion specification reads white-space delimited words — presumably, that's what you mean by 'records' since that's the function and format you're using.

```
size_t count = 0;
while (fscanf(in, "%*s") == 0)
    count++;

printf("There are %zu words in the input\n", count);
```

You could use a fixed store like this:

```
int offset = 0;
size_t count = 0;

while (fscanf(in, "%*s%n", &offset) == 0 && offset != 0)
{
    count++;
    offset = 0;
}
```

The [`scanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/scanf.html) manual page repays careful reading, and re-reading, and re-re-reading.

---

The same basic idea of assignment suppression applies to the `"%s %d"` record format.  The problem is that suppressed conversions are not counted in the return value from `fscanf()` — and the `%n` conversion specifications aren't counted either.  So, you can use:

```
int offset = 0;
size_t count = 0;

while (fscanf(in, "%*s %*d%n", &offset) == 0 && offset != 0)
{
    count++;
    offset = 0;
}
```

which is only a trivial modification of what went before.  If either the `%*s` or `%*d` conversions fails, the `%n` won't be executed, so `offset` won't be changed.  If both are successful, then `offset` will be assigned a value larger than zero (because the string must be at least one character, and the number must be at least one character, and there must be at least one blank between the string and the number).  So, the code shown detects whether the read was successful.

Comment: 1+ not just only for the so true "re-re"s! :)